# About kissing fractions and their lower/upper bound

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, fractions

So I read about this part from the textbook Illustrated Theory of Numbers (by Martin Weissman). The link to the part: https://illustratedtheoryofnumbers.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/fractions-and-semiotics/

Which states that 2 fractions $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$ "kisses" if and only if $ad - bc = 1$  or $= -1$

Say we have $\frac{2}{3}$ , I can find $\frac{x}{y}$ that kisses $\frac{2}{3}$ by solving Diophantine equation $2y - 3x = 1$ or $2y - 3x = -1$.

By solving for $f(x,y) = 1$, I get a general formula for $\frac{x}{y}$ which is $\frac{2n+1}{3n+2}$ such that it will be smaller than $\frac{2}{3}$. And:

$\frac{2n+1}{3n+1}$ such that $\frac{x}{y}$ will be bigger than $\frac{2}{3}$ for the case of $f(x,y) = -1$ for all integers n.

Why is this the case?

Comment: I don't understand this at all. $\frac23$ is kissed by fractions less than itself and by fractions greater than itself. What is it that you find surprising?

Comment: I just need an explanation or proof for so that if one ask me: "find all fractions that kiss 2/3 but less than it", I can show them why I solve for 1 instead of solving for -1 etc.

Comment: OK, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that $\frac ab-\frac cd=\frac{ad-bc}{bd}$. So, assuming $b$ and $d$ are positive, $\frac cd$ is smaller than $\frac ab$ if $ad-bc>0$ and larger is $ad-bc<0$.

If this is $\pm 1$ then it will be greater or less by the minimum possible amount, given the size of its denominator.

Comment: got it, thank you!